# How to get the values of data from each cluster by using kmeans algorithm

Tags: matlab

After I perform **k-means algorithm** of Matlab, I get the number of the desired clusters. Now, if I want to see the data points of each cluster, how will I proceed. Is there any command in Matlab that would help me get that? Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thank You.

```
CC=F'
[idx,C]=kmeans(CC,15);
for i = 1:15
    data{i} = [CC(idx==i)] ;
end
```

Comment: Have you tried to google your question: [I need to know each point to which cluster in kmeans fun.](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/45064-i-need-to-know-each-point-to-which-cluster-in-kmeans-fun)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*I want to see the data points of each cluster*" ?  There are many ways to visualise the clusters. And depending on the number of dimensions of your data some of those ways are more or less useful.

Comment: Without knowing the variable `CC` (or a sample of it) we cannot really help you, we can only guess. My guess is, however, that it is multidimensional, thus `CC(idx==i)` should instead be `CC(idx==i,:)` (or alike). Also the brackets, `[]`, around `CC(idx==i)` are superfluous.